# Angular 4 AOT with webpack integration

Tags: angular, webpack, aot, angular4-aot

After configure AOT with webpack in angular 4, i am facing following issue

```
 ERROR in : "let-" is only supported on ng-template elements. ("<template ngFor [ngForOf]="parts" [ER
ROR ->]let-part let-isOdd="odd"><span *ngIf="isOdd" class="{{highlightClass}}">{{part}}</span><templ
ate [ngI")
: "let-" is only supported on ng-template elements. ("<template ngFor [ngForOf]="parts" let-part [ER
ROR ->]let-isOdd="odd"><span *ngIf="isOdd" class="{{highlightClass}}">{{part}}</span><template [ngIf
]="!isOd")
```

I have already converted every template to ng-template. BUT still not sure what causing this error.

Any help is really appricated.

Comment: Are you still using an old library or something that is still generating `<template>`?

Comment: thats right. I was using ng-bootstrap which was not compatiable and need to be update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am able to fix this issue after upgrading one of my library i.e. ng-bootstrap.

Usually these type of error occurs, when we use some of old version dependencies.